# Cleaner way to write a specific object mapper in Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I wrote a mapper in Ramda that simplifies an object and removes properties that have empty array. It is a very simple thing for what it does but the Ramda helper methods I had to put together will cause me to scratch my head in few weeks time when I look into the function.

I wonder if there is a cleaner way to achieve the same result.

Here's the code:

```
const filters = {
  Brand: [],
  BusinessUnit: [
    {
      FilterName: 'BusinessUnit',
      KeyItem: 'Beauty'
    },
    {
      FilterName: 'BusinessUnit',
      KeyItem: 'Sports'
    }
  ],
  Category: [],
  SKU: [
    {
      FilterName: 'SKU',
      KeyItem: '9023'
    }
  ]
}

const expectedFilters = {
  BusinessUnit: ['Beauty', 'Sports'],
  SKU: ['9023']
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// is there any way to write it cleaner

const result = R.compose(
  R.pickBy(R.pipe(R.isEmpty, R.not)),
  R.map(R.map(R.prop('KeyItem')))
)(filters);

///////////////////////////////////////////////

console.log('(expectedFilters:: ', expectedFilters);
console.log('result:: ', result);
console.log('is equal? ', R.equals(expectedFilters, result)); // true
```

Here's the link to this code running on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ramda-simple-object-mapper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

[@codepic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308847/codeepic) pointed out that this is still better with `reject` in place of combining `filter` and `complement`.  This is a clearly superior solution:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  reject (isEmpty), 
  map (pluck ('KeyItem') )
)

const filters = {Brand: [], BusinessUnit: [{FilterName: 'BusinessUnit', KeyItem: 'Beauty'}, {FilterName: 'BusinessUnit', KeyItem: 'Sports'}], Category: [], SKU: [{FilterName: 'SKU', KeyItem: '9023'}]}

console .log (
  transform (filters)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, reject, isEmpty, map, pluck} = R   </script>
```

### Original Answer

There is definitely some clean-up to be had.  I think `complement (isEmpty)` is much cleaner than `pipe (isEmpty, not)`.  And `map (prop ('foo') )` has a built-in function, `pluck ('foo')`.  And while `pickBy` will work fine, it became redundant some time ago, since `filter` will cover objects as well as arrays.

So my *(now outdated)* version would look like this:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  filter (complement (isEmpty) )
  map (pluck ('KeyItem') )
)

const filters = {Brand: [], BusinessUnit: [{FilterName: 'BusinessUnit', KeyItem: 'Beauty'}, {FilterName: 'BusinessUnit', KeyItem: 'Sports'}], Category: [], SKU: [{FilterName: 'SKU', KeyItem: '9023'}]}

console .log (
  transform (filters)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, filter, complement, isEmpty, map, pluck} = R   </script>
```

And of course, there is an argument to be made for extracting `complement (isEmpty)` to `notEmpty` and possibly extracting `filter (notEmpty)` to something like `removeEmpties`.  Obviously those are easy to do.

Comment: I didn't realise `filter` worked with objects and I keep forgetting about `pluck`. That's obviously better +1

Comment: I like your transform function - very clean. I would take it one step forward and instead of `filter)complement(isEmpty)` I would use `reject(isEmpty)` to decrease cognitive load for the future code reader even more and swap the order of two lines in `transform` as suggested by @customcommander function so first we remove the empty arrays and then we map.

Comment: Just realised that my advice on swapping lines in `transform` function is not valid since you're using `pipe` instead of `compose`.

Comment: That's ok, @customcommander: I'm one of the authors, and I forgot that `reject` works with objects as well.  That's a much better answer @codepic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong or complicated with your solution.

The only adjustments I'd make are:

1. Replace `R.pickBy(R.pipe(R.isEmpty, R.not))` with `R.pickBy(R.complement(R.isEmpty))`.
2. Pick before you map. (Currently, you're mapping over empty arrays)